# Drawing a line over an image in Crystal Reports for VS2010

Tags: crystal-reports

This question has been posted countless times before and only workarounds have been given. Thing is that all the answers I have found are for versions 8.5 of Crystal Reports or earlier which is over two years old. Since SAP was notified of the problem I am guessing they might have fixed it or made a good workaround which I might have missed.

**Is there any good method I can use to make a line object appear over an image object in *Crystal Reports for VS2010*?**

Move to front / move to back methods don't work. Also using the `Underlay Following Sections` does not work.

[Here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1916479) is a more detailed discussion on what I am trying to achieve. Please note I am aware of most of the workarounds given online but I am looking for a more practical way to achieve this.

Comment: Crystal Reports 8.5 is more than a decade old.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the easier solution be to alternate between the image and an image with a line (contained in the image itself)?

Comment: Since my report will probably need to be modified a good number of times in the future, no.

Comment: Could you expand on the purpose of the line?  It is denoting 'end of something' (like what is done in Europe to denote when you leave a town) or another reason?

Comment: The line is part of a fixed size table.